# Codeigniter: SUM of two columns

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having problem getting the sum of the columns.
it would be something like `SUM('billing_amount' - billing_philhealth)`

I tried the following code but didn't solve the problem...

```
<?php
                       $this->db->where('billing_id', $data->billing_id);
                       $this->db->select_sum(('billing_amount') - ('billing_philhealth'));
                       $query3 = $this->db->get('billing_entry');
                       $x = 1;
                            foreach ($query3->result() as $tot)
                            {   
                                echo '<h3>₱'.$tot->billing_amount.'</h3>';
                                echo '<input type="hidden" name="total_amount" id="totAmt" value="'.$tot->billing_amount.'">';
                            } 
                ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$this->db->select('SUM(field1) + SUM(field2) + SUM(field3) as total', FALSE);
```

FALSE stops auto escapipng

Comment: sure. wait for 5 mins man. ;)